# Nmtui as non-root user Centos 7.1

Tags: centos, networkmanager, non-root-user

Trying to run `nmtui` as a non-root user to edit network connections.

As it stands I get a `Unable to save connection: Insufficient privileges` error.

I've tried setting the `USERCTL=no` to `USERCTL=yes` in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-MYINTERACE` file, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The USERCTL parameter does not mean what you think it means.

From: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html (same meaning in later versions):

> USERCTL=`<answer>`, where `<answer>` is one of the following:
>
> - yes — Non-root users are allowed to control this device.
> - no — Non-root users are not allowed to control this device.

Where "control" here means "bring the interface up and down". The error you're getting is because nmtui is unable to overwrite a root-owned file with your non-root userid.

Comment: I've set the /etc/sysconfig.network-scripts dir and the containing files to be owned by user:user but still get the same error.

Comment: I would recommend that route as a solution. Use sudo or su to get to root, then use nmtui.

Comment: wow, I missed an important word in my previous comment. I would *not* recommend that (changing ownership of /etc/sysconfig directories to a user) as a solution!

Comment: nmtui does not write to any files directly, but uses D-Bus. Whatever the problem here, it's not necessary to run nmtui as root (permissions are checked via PolicyKit). I'd check the "connection.permissions" value as shown by `nmcli connection show $NAME`.